# "Recent" lists on start and taskbar despite turning it off

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, start-menu, windows-10-v1809

Since updating to Windows 10 1809, right clicking on start and taskbar icons shows a list of recent documents. When going to **Settings, Personalization, Start**, and then checking and unchecking "**Show recently opened items...**" it helps for a short time, but then the issue returns.

Is there any way to stop it?

Comment: What's your system version? My version is Windows10 1809 OS build 17763.134. It works fine. If you haven't updated to the latest version, I suggest that you could try.

Comment: @daidai I have the same Build.